# d3js column bar chart height error

Tags: d3.js

i'm trying to replicate [this simple column bar chart](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/bar-2.html) in d3 except also use negative values. I was able to figure out how to use negative values, but now my axis seems to be off. I think it's probably something I'm doing with the y-values.

Here's where I'm drawing the bars:

```
var chart = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("class","chart")
        .attr("width", w * data.length - 1)
        .append("g")
        .attr("height", h);


chart.selectAll("rect")
     .data(data)
     .attr("class","rect")
     .enter().append("rect")
     .attr("x", function(d, i) { return x(i) - .5; })
     .attr("y", function(d) { return h - y(d.value) - .5; })
     .attr("width", w)
     .attr("height", function(d) { return Math.abs(y(d.value) - y(0)); });
```

and here's a fiddle with everything: http://jsfiddle.net/Y4wAC/2/

I just want to have the x-axis at 0 and all the bars originating from the x-axis which is probably really simple but i'm a n00b

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need to move the line up by adjusting the `y` coordinate. In your case, this is easiest done by subtracting `y(0)` from `height`, i.e.

```
.attr("y1", h - y(0))
.attr("y2", h - y(0))
```

Updated jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Y4wAC/3/).

Comment: yep, thanks Lars. added this too to align the one negative bar: 

    .attr("x", function(d, i) { return x(i) - .5; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return d.value < 0 ? h - y(0) : h - y(d.value) - .5;

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y4wAC/4/

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to flip the domain on the y scale so you are working from 0 to h and work from a y0 position, as Lars mentioned:

```
var height = function(d){ return Math.abs(y(d.value) - y(0));}
var ypos = function(d){return d.value < 0 ? y(0) : y(0) - height(d);}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XryuS/

The big difference is adding some logic to calculate the ypos for negative values that belong below the y0 point. This also has to be reflected when you calculate the height.

Your example worked with a y0 at the the bottom of the container which means for the smallest value (-3) your example drew a rectangle from 0 to 30 instead of from 70 to 100.